# Using node.js for rendering in the electron application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, electron

During the script operation `render.js` , imported into `index.html` some modules and tools for working with the node file system are node.js, but their use is impossible, because in `render.js` uses pure JS (not node) and for example importing modules using `require()` will cause an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at render.js:1:9
```

Code element from `render.js`  that caused the error:

```
var $ = require( "jquery" );

...
```

How can I implement the use of such in the electron application?

I tried to implement this by creating a new server process written in node.js and sending HTTP requests to it from `render.js`, but my knowledge was not enough to implement such a method, and I did not find any more or less understandable examples. In addition, I am almost sure that there is another way or a ready-made tool to solve this problem.

My experience in this field is extremely small, I can be wrong. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: You will need to make your `render.js` browser compatible by using a bundler such as Browserify, Rollup, Webpack. etc.